# WorkLighr 6.0 Deployement on windows 8 issue

Tags: windows-8, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I am still working to ibm-worklight 6.0 mobile application , it's working fine my local eclipse development server. but i am going to install the the liberty based using WAS server while i deploye the worklight WAR file is not working. am i got the error below that,

> Exception thrown by application class
>   'com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter:110'
>   javax.servlet.ServletException: Worklight Project not initialized at
>   com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:110)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:194)
>   at [internal classes]

What is exactly problem on my application or server installation

Answer (score 0):

This normally comes if the AuthenticationConfig file is having errors, re-check your authentication config and worklight.properties file. Make sure that while deploying for remote server, you have changed the Servername / URL etc